# Error while appending in a list in python

Tags: python

this is for a school project and  this is just a part of the code where the error exists the error comes when i try to append my second variable

```
 def info():
    f=open('info.txt','a')
    ch='y'
    while ch=='y':
        l=[]
        x=raw_input('enter staff id')
        l=l.append(x)
        dob=raw_input("enter date of birth")
        l=l.append(dob)
        doj=raw_input('enter date of joining')
        l=l.append(doj)
        t=raw_input('enter duty time')
        l=l.append(t)
        sal=input('enter salary per month')
        l=l.append(sal)
        f.append(l)
        ch=raw_input('want to enter more info')
```

The error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#1>", line 1, in <module>
    info()
  File "C:/Python27/staff info.py", line 9, in info
    l=l.append(dob)
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'append'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`list.append()` returns `None` because the list is altered in place.

Don't assign the return value, there is no need to:

```
x=raw_input('enter staff id')
l.append(x)
```

Comment: Sorry but still not able to get it can you please elaborate

Comment: @SarthakKinger: remove all the `l=` assignments; you replaced your list with `None` every time you do that.

Comment: thank you now i got it  Martijn Pieters